# Binary 3D fuzzy matrix in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I have a fuzzy matrix M that size is `3x3x3`such that

```
M(:,:,1)+M(:,:,2)+M(:,:,3)=matrix one %all elements is one
0<=M(:,:,i)<=1; i=1..3
```

I want to covert the matrix M to binary matrix such that

```
if (M(p,q,i)>=M(p,q,j)) then M(p,q,i)=1, M(p,q,j)=0
```

where p,q is position of a element. i,j=1..3

Note that if we already set  `M(p,q,i)=1` then `M(p,q,j)` must be `0` (j=1..3, j!=i) because I want to sum of binary matrix M still equals 1 (sum(M,3)=ones(3,
3))

Could you help me perform that idea in matlab? Thank you so much

For example:

```
M=zeros([3 3 3]);
M(:,:,1) =  [0.2000    0.3000    0.4000;
             0.5000    0.6000    0.7000;
             0.3000    0.2000    0.1000];


M(:,:,2) =  [0.4000    0.1000    0.6000;
             0.1000    0.3000    0.1000;
             0.1000    0.2000    0.1000];


M(:,:,3) =  [0.4000    0.6000         0;
             0.4000    0.1000    0.2000;
             0.6000    0.6000    0.8000];
```

My expected output is

```
M_out(:,:,1)=[0        0         0;
              1        1         1
              0        0         0];

M_out(:,:,2)=[1        0         1;
              0        0         0
              0        0         0];

M_out(:,:,3)=[0        1         0;
              0        0         0
              1        1         1];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) & [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) duo solve it for a `generic` and `vectorized` solution -

```
%// Get max indices along dim-3
[~,idx] = max(M,[],3);

%// Setup o/p logical array with same size as M and 1s at starting max indices
M_out = bsxfun(@eq,idx,permute(1:size(M,3),[1 3 2]))
```

Sample run -

```
>> M
M(:,:,1) =
          0.2          0.3          0.4
          0.5          0.6          0.7
          0.3          0.2          0.1
M(:,:,2) =
          0.4          0.1          0.6
          0.1          0.3          0.1
          0.1          0.2          0.1
M(:,:,3) =
          0.4          0.6            0
          0.4          0.1          0.2
          0.6          0.6          0.8
>> [~,idx] = max(M,[],3);
M_out = bsxfun(@eq,idx,permute(1:size(M,3),[1 3 2]))
M_out(:,:,1) =
     0     0     0
     1     1     1
     0     0     0
M_out(:,:,2) =
     1     0     1
     0     0     0
     0     0     0
M_out(:,:,3) =
     0     1     0
     0     0     0
     1     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one solution for you. However, it is so long code if `N` is increased

```
M12=M(:,:,1)>=M(:,:,2);
M13=M(:,:,1)>=M(:,:,3);
M_out(:,:,1)=M12.*M13

M21=M(:,:,2)>M(:,:,1); %"we already set M(p,q,i)=1 then M(p,q,j) must be 0 (j=1..3, j!=i)"
M23=M(:,:,2)>=M(:,:,3);
M_out(:,:,2)=M21.*M23

M31=M(:,:,3)>M(:,:,1);% "we already set M(p,q,i)=1 then M(p,q,j) must be 0 (j=1..3, j!=i)" 
M32=M(:,:,3)>M(:,:,2);% "we already set M(p,q,i)=1 then M(p,q,j) must be 0 (j=1..3, j!=i)"
M_out(:,:,3)=M31.*M32

%%Checking
sum(M_out,3)
```

Comment: It worked for me but it is better using loop function that can ignore the writing all cases

Answer (score 0):

this code does almost exactly what you asked for, the only difference is that when the max is the same (i.e. M(p,q,i)==M(p,q,j)) it writes a 1 to both locations (i and j).

Here is the code:

```
M=zeros([3 3 3]);
M(:,:,1) =  [0.2000    0.3000    0.4000;
             0.5000    0.6000    0.7000;
             0.3000    0.2000    0.1000];


M(:,:,2) =  [0.4000    0.1000    0.6000;
             0.1000    0.3000    0.1000;
             0.1000    0.2000    0.1000];


M(:,:,3) =  [0.4000    0.6000         0;
             0.4000    0.1000    0.2000;
             0.6000    0.6000    0.8000];

output = zeros(size(M));
for i = 1:size(M,1)
    for j = 1:size(M,2)
        for k = 1:size(M,3)
            if M(i,j,k) == max(M(i,j,:))
                output(i,j,k) = 1;
            else
                output(i,j,k) = 0;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Please tell me if it works for you or if putting 1 in both locations is a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks underscore_nico. It does not satisfy condition sum(M_out,3)=1; As I run your code, the output(1,1,3)=1 and output(1,1,2)=1. I want to output(1,1,2)=1 then output(1,1,3) must be 0